# Is there a DSL for writing Regular Expressions?

Tags: regex, dsl

I'm wondering if there is a DSL(domain specific language) for writing Regular Expression?  I know "few" people that actually can read and understand regular expression and it seems that a language abstraction that "compiles" to regular expressions would be an awesome win if one exists.  Thanks!

Comment: Another perspective: Look at regular expressions as a "DSL" for regular automata.

Comment: regular expressions already are a domain specific language -- a language for parsing expressions. It may not be very human-friendly but it _is_ a language for a very specific domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't stated your platform, but assuming C# based on your other tags, you might want to look at [LINQ to Regex](http://osherove.com/blog/2008/5/6/introducing-linq-to-regex.html). I'm not sure it's really a good idea, but it's the closest I've heard of to what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs has an sexp DSL for regexps: http://repo.or.cz/w/emacs.git/blob/HEAD:/lisp/emacs-lisp/rx.el

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a DSL, but for those who don't understand regex, there's the
**[Regular Expression Analyzer](http://xenon.stanford.edu/~xusch/regexp/analyzer.html)**

Answer (score 0):

[PEGs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar) are a much more readable (and more powerful) alternative to regular expressions. If you're looking for something semantically equivalent to the normal regexps, then any implementation which allows comments and whitespaces would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [REL, an open-source regex DSL](http://imaginatio.github.io/REL/).

It is in scala, but you can export/translate your regexes into other [flavors](http://imaginatio.github.io/REL/Tree+rewriting+&+Flavors.html#Flavors) like .NET.